# Nested query with joins via intermediate M:N (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck on a problem that I'm trying to solve, hoping for some help...

Here is a layout of the database:

[image: database]

The objective is as follows:

[image: problem objective]

note:

```
name1 - supplier (e.g., S1, S2, etc.)
name3 - component (e.g., C1, C2, etc.)
name5 - assembly (e.g., A1, A2, etc.)
output - cost for various combinations of supplier-component
```

The following (incomplete) query I developed finds the minimum outputs with respect to the component level (III), but it does not perform the intermediate step of adding the minimums at the multi-component assembly level (II) as the desired query.

```
select t5.name5, min(output) as min_output
from t5
inner join t4
    on t5.id5 = t4.id5
inner join t2
    on t4.id3 = t2.id3
group by t5.name5
order by t5.id5
;
```

The resulting incorrect output only shows the following:

```
name5          min_output
-----|---------------------------
A    | minimum of component A
B    | minimum of component B
```

desired result is Level II sum of A & B's Level III components (minimized with respect to output), for each listed Level I/name5 (i.e., minimized assembly cost using the corresponding components/suppliers).

How can I solve this with the above query, if at all? I feel like I'm missing some nested conditions.

Additionally, how would I determine if any entries from t1 (suppliers) have been unused? Would I use an outer join somehow?

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT 2**

Per Gordon's suggestion, here is the full data set for reference as code:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DB;

USE DB;

CREATE TABLE t3 (
    id3 INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name3 VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id3)
);

CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id1 INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name1 VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id1)
);

CREATE TABLE t5 (
    id5 INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name5 VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id5)
);

CREATE TABLE t4 (
    id5 INT,
    id3 INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id5)
        REFERENCES t5 (id5),
    FOREIGN KEY (id3)
        REFERENCES t3 (id3)
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
    id2 INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    id1 INT,
    id3 INT,
    output INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id2),
    FOREIGN KEY (id1)
        REFERENCES t1 (id1),
    FOREIGN KEY (id3)
        REFERENCES t3 (id3)
);

insert into t3(name3)
    values('C1');
insert into t3(name3)
    values('CS2');
insert into t3(name3)
    values('C3');
insert into t3(name3)
    values('C4');
insert into t3(name3)
    values('C5');
insert into t3(name3)
    values('C6');

insert into t1(name1)
    values('S1');
insert into t1(name1)
    values('S2');
insert into t1(name1)
    values('S3');
insert into t1(name1)
    values('S4');
insert into t1(name1)
    values('S5');

insert into t5(name5)
    values('A1');
insert into t5(name5)
    values('A2'); 
insert into t5(name5)
    values('A3');  
insert into t5(name5)
    values('A4');

insert into t4(id5, id3)
    values(1,1);
insert into t4(id5, id3)
    values(2,2);
insert into t4(id5, id3)
    values(2,3);
insert into t4(id5, id3)
    values(3,4);
insert into t4(id5, id3)
    values(3,5);
insert into t4(id5, id3)
    values(4,6);
insert into t4(id5, id3)
    values(4,3);

insert into t2(id1, id3, output)
    values(1,1,121);
insert into t2(id1, id3, output)
    values(1,2,135);
insert into t2(id1, id3, output)
    values(2,2,94);    
insert into t2(id1, id3, output)
    values(2,3,155);
insert into t2(id1, id3, output)
    values(3,3,178);
insert into t2(id1, id3, output)
    values(3,4,199);
insert into t2(id1, id3, output)
    values(4,4,122);
insert into t2(id1, id3, output)
    values(4,5,155);
insert into t2(id1, id3, output)
    values(5,5,133);
insert into t2(id1, id3, output)
    values(5,6,184);
```

output from my original query is as follows:

```
name5          min_output
-----|---------------------------
A1   |       121
A2   |       94
A3   |       122
A4   |       155
```

expected output is:

```
name5          min_output
-----|---------------------------
A1   |       121
A2   |       249
A3   |       255
A4   |       339
```

Additionally, how would I determine if any entries from t1 (suppliers) have been unused? Would I use an outer join with NULL somehow based on the (correct) results table?

expected output:

```
unused_name1
--------------|
       S3     |
```

P.S. Good call, thanks Gordon!

Comment: Sample data *as a text table in the query* and desired results in the same format would be a big help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gordon, I have added data for the tables as SQL code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following query will solve your problem; it is basically your query but moving the min(output) into a subquery on t2, thus allowing a sum to be done at the top level:

```
select t5.name5, sum(t2m.cost) as min_output
from t5 
left join t4 on t4.id5 = t5.id5 
left join (select id3, min(output) as cost from t2 group by id3) as t2m on t2m.id3 = t4.id3 
group by t5.name5 
order by t5.id5
```

Output:

```
 name5  min_output  
 A1     121
 A2     249
 A3     255
 A4     339
```

In terms of the unused supplier/component pairs (i.e. suppliers whose component cost is higher than the minimum), this query will retrieve them:

```
select distinct t1.name1, t2.id3
from t5
left join t4
    on t4.id5 = t5.id5
left join t2
    on t2.id3 = t4.id3
left join t1
    on t1.id1 = t2.id1
where t2.output != (select min(output) from t2 where id3 = t4.id3)
order by t1.id1
```

Output:

```
 name1  id3     
 S1     2
 S3     3
 S3     4
 S4     5
```

This query will give a list of suppliers which don't have any minimum cost components, along with the number of components they supply (to get just the name, you could select name from this as a subquery).

```
select t1.name1, t1c.cmpcount
from t5
left join t4
    on t4.id5 = t5.id5
left join t2
    on t2.id3 = t4.id3
left join t1
    on t1.id1 = t2.id1
left join (select id1, count(id3) as cmpcount from t2 group by id1) as t1c
    on t1c.id1 = t2.id1
where t2.output != (select min(output) from t2 where id3 = t4.id3)
group by t1.name1
having count(distinct t2.id3) = t1c.cmpcount
```

Output

```
name1   cmpcount    
S3      2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Nick, the subquery was the smoking gun! Regarding the second part, what I'm looking for is just the output of the unused suppliers. From the given data set, the expected output would be simply S3, as they did not provide any minimum-cost components in any of the assemblies. Does that make sense? The query you provided is showing all suppliers that weren't used in a given subassembly, but I'm looking for just any suppliers that were not used at all based on the minimum-cost constraint. Thanks again!!!